# Contact form 7 POST URL not found - 404

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, contact-form-7

When I click the submit button on my contact form 7 form, I get a `404 Not Found` error status on the POST URL.

From what I can see, the Request URL has two trailing slashes after /wp-json/ .

e.g Request URL: `//mywebsite.com/wp-json//contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/3/feedback`

I disabled all plugins, saved permalinks, deleted cache and in general, I have tried every solution I could find on the web.

The permalinks in WordPress have a custom structure with `/%postname%/` at the end. If I disable the custom structure and leave the permalinks "plain" the form works fine but I don't want this solution as it breaks down the rest website.

```
WordPress Version: 4.9.8,   
Contact Form 7 Version: 5.1.1
```

---

This is my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.git+ - [R=404,L] #Return 404 for files in .git folder
RewriteRule ^/?vendor/(.*)$ - [R=403,L] #Return 403 for files in vendor folder
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?bin+ - [R=404,L] #Return 404 for files in bin folder
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: You can check your console error??